# How can I replace the value of a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is my code:

```js
var str = 'http://localhost/myweb/login/resend_password?destination=http://localhost%2Fmyweb%2Fsearch%3Fs%3Dislamic_sources%26q%3D%25D8%25B3%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585';

var res = str.replace('/(destination=)[^$|&]+/', '$1newval');

console.log(res);
```

While this is expected result:

```
http://localhost/myweb/login/resend_password?destination=newval
```

Why the replace doesn't work in my code? Noted that it works in [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/sYCEiX/2/).

Comment: Remove quotes around *literal notation*.

Comment: Yep, it's a typo. You're trying to replace a string, not a regex. `var res = str.replace('/(destination=)[^$|&]+/', '$1newval');` should be `var res = str.replace(/(destination=)[^$|&]+/, '$1newval');`

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question? I've tried so much before asking and I've added a fiddle in my question and it's pretty much clear. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```js
var str = 'http://localhost/myweb/login/resend_password?destination=http://localhost%2Fmyweb%2Fsearch%3Fs%3Dislamic_sources%26q%3D%25D8%25B3%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585';

var res = str.replace(/(destination=)[^&]*/, '$1newval');

console.log(res);
```

Regex should not be in quotes and regex needed some fix as `[^$|&]+` doesn't do what you think it is doing.

`[^$|&]+` matches any character that is not a `$` and not a `|` and not a `&`

instead of just non-`&` characters.

Comment: Ah I see, thx, just may you please tell me how can I define this in regex? *"match any character until either `&` or end of line"*

Comment: That's what I provided in my answer. `[^&]*` will match 0 more of any character until `&` or end of input.

Comment: Ah ok thx. Just as a side note, do you know what's the equivalent of `\K` in JS? I want to avoid matching `destination=` in the pattern. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/sYCEiX/3) but in JS

Comment: `\K` is PCRE specific so unfortunately not available in JS. Using `\K` you can only avoid a capturing group. capturing group is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

put the reg expression without ' like this

```js
var str = 'http://localhost/myweb/login/resend_password?destination=http://localhost%2Fmyweb%2Fsearch%3Fs%3Dislamic_sources%26q%3D%25D8%25B3%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585';

var res = str.replace(/(destination=)[^$|&]+/, '$1newval');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

the following solutions works 
`

```
var str = 'http://localhost/myweb/login/resend_password?destination=http://localhost%2Fmyweb%2Fsearch%3Fs%3Dislamic_sources%26q%3D%25D8%25B3%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585';
var regexpr= /(destination=)[^$|&]+/g;
var res = str.replace(regexpr, '$1newval');
console.log(res);
```

`
you have to remove the quotes!